# how to run target from post build events using MSBuild

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I want to run a target in csproj file using post build events from the visual studio properties window (not from cmd promt).

Is that possible? Please explains thks

Answer (score 6):

You can define a target called AfterBuild in your csproj file and it will be called near the end of the build process. There is also a BeforeBuild target you can add that gets called just before the core build actions.

Comment: yes. That is a valid point. But I like to call it from the post build events from visual studio properties. Please let me know if there is a way..thks

Comment: The msbuild scripts do an Exec task on the text in the post build event, so you could call MSBuild to execute some project file and run a target that way - if you MUST do it with post build events. The "visual studio properties" are MSBuild properties so you can access them in the AfterBuild target.

Comment: Can you please show me how to write that(syntax) and the second way I dont see any AfterBuild target in properties->BuildEvents. I can only see Post-build event command line.

Comment: There is no user interface in Visual Studio to do the AfterBuild event. You would edit the csproj directly as a text file. Add a target with a name of AfterBuild and then add the MSBuild targets/tasks you want to call.

Comment: Here is a link that describes some of the integration points available in the csproj file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx

Comment: All these links say modify the cproj file by added different target names. What exactly i was looking for is calling a target or execute some commands from post build events...

Comment: If you really want to do it from a post build event just execute msbuild from the post build event passing in a proj file that contains the target you want to execute. In that case you will need to pass the properties you want to that instance of msbuild. To execute in the same msbuild instance add to the AfterBuild target and from there you can call other targets.